# Query not listing duplicate records in sql?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, select, subquery, linked-server

I am using below query to find duplicate records

```
SELECT F.ID,f.CIVILID
FROM DBO.EMPUDF AS F
WHERE f.civilid IN (SELECT CIVILID
                    FROM dBO.EMPUDF
                    GROUP BY CIVILID
                    HAVING COUNT (CIVILID) > 1)
```

The subquery returns 218 records which are duplicate records, but when I try to execute the query to return name and id it returns more than 10k records with many null id columns.

Comment: Nothing strange. Each of 218 `civilid` has 2 to 10,000 records with (possibly) different `ID`.

Comment: @AlexKudryashev , i need to select  218 records with names

Comment: @coffemug,  you have to handle null value either in subquery or in outer query.

Comment: @YogeshSharma ,  I added a where clause  `where civil is not null`  , even the result is same

Comment: then show ur query attemp & desired result.

Comment: @YogeshSharma ,  i used below answer and its  retrieving around 10k records

Comment: pls. show your data that query return.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, you are dealing with duplicates, so there are a lot of them.

You can get an idea of how many are duplicated by doing a histogram of histograms:

```
SELECT cnt, COUNT(*), MIN(CIVILID), MAX(CIVILID)
FROM (SELECT CIVILID, COUNT(*) as cnt
      FROM  dBO.EMPUDF
      GROUP BY CIVILID
     ) c
GROUP BY cnt
ORDER BY cnt;
```

Also, your original query is more simply written using window functions:

```
SELECT e.*
FROM (SELECT e.*, COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY CIVILID) as cnt
      FROM  dBO.EMPUDF
     ) e
WHERE cnt > 1;
```

Comment: How to list names along with civilid in your query

Comment: Tthe query is printing around 10 k records including null  id column, even though i added is not null in where clause.